Macro to get DateTaken of a picture, video
Is it possible to get DateTaken info of an picture or video file by means of a macro?
I found a macro to get file creation date and time but when I copy a picture for example to google drive, file creation date becomes copying date. But I need the date-time the picture is taken.
Thank you,
Aganta Horanta

Macro in what context? What's your programming language and programming-related problem?
